# Reason for || behind read

Tags: shell-script

I'm currently cleaning up my server and had I look at a script which works and of whose existence I was aware of, but I can't figure out what's the reasoning behind the `| [ "$VAR" ]`.

```
while read VAR || [ "$VAR" ]
do
    [...]
done < inputfile
```

Fun fact: I wrote this script a few years ago...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482525/108618

Comment: Cool. Make it an answer.

Comment: I will pass. You answer if you wish. Give credit to the author of the linked answer, don't mention me.

Comment: I'd be slightly surprised if there is no SuperUser question that actually has this already. In any case, you're free to build upon my U&L answer if you wish.